# Python catch custom warning class without stopping execution of code

Tags: python, error-handling

I am creating an application that takes a command from a user, validates that the command is legitimate, and then executes the command.

The basic flow is that the `receive_message` function is triggered when the user places a request. That `receive_message` function then routes the function request to the correct helper function depending on what the user is requesting to do.

There are 2 types of exceptional cases that I want to handle -- Errors and Warnings. Errors should occur when the action is not possible. Warnings should occur when the action is possible, but potentially will not behave in the way the user expected.

Right now I handle errors by raising a `CustomError` class in the helper functions. For example,

```
circularity = is_circular_reference(column_id, reference)
if circularity:
  raise CustomError()
```

That exception is then caught in the `receive_message` function which has the following code

```
try:
       self.handle_request(event)
       self.send({success: True})
         
except CustomError as e:
        print(get_recent_traceback())
        print(e)
        
        response = {
            'event': 'edit_error',
            'id': event['id'],
            'type': e.type_,
            'header': e.header,
            'to_fix': e.to_fix
        }
        
        self.send(response)
```

I'd like to be able to handle the `CustomWarning` in a similar manner, with the difference that raising a `CustomWarning` should not stop the execution of the function. When a warning is thrown, the entire `self.handle_request(event)` should finish executing, and then I should catch the warning to send it back to the frontend.

For example, I want to check if I should throw a warning in a similar way that I check for errors:

```
warning_required = is_warning_required(column_id, reference)
if warning_required:
      raise CustomWarning()
```

And then I want to extend the `receive_message` function so that its like the following:

```
try:
       self.handle_request(event)
       self.send({success: True})
         
except CustomError as e:
        print(get_recent_traceback())
        print(e)
        
        response = {
            'event': 'edit_error',
            'id': event['id'],
            'type': e.type_,
            'header': e.header,
            'to_fix': e.to_fix
        }
        
        self.send(response)


except CustomWarning as w:
          response = {
                'event': 'edit_warning',
                'id': event['id'],
                'type': e.type_,
                'header': e.header,
                'warning_message': e.warning_message
            }
```

Comment: As soon as you `raise`, it breaks the current control flow, similar to a `return` -- it doesn't matter what the caller does in the `except`.  `handle_request` is the thing that needs to change, not its caller.

Answer (score 0):

You can't defer exceptions like this: their purpose is to allow a flow control to *immediately* skip to the nearest enclosing `try` statement that catches the exception.

What you want is for `handle_request` to simply build and return an appropriate response.

```
try:
    response = self.handle_request(event)
except CustomError as e:
    print(get_recent_traceback())
    print(e)

    response = { ... }

self.send(response)
```

where `handle_request` itself returns either `{"success": True}` or `{"event": "edit_warning", ...}`. Once the `try` statement is complete, `response` will refer to an appropriate value to pass to `self.send`